# How i can subtract one float variable with an int

Tags: pointers

```
int main(){

int V1;
float V2;
bool V3 = true;

int *Ptr1;
int *Ptr2;


*Ptr1 = V1;
*Ptr2 = V2;

cout << "Enter the worth of V1: " << endl;
cin >> *Ptr1;

cout << "Enter the worth of V2: " << endl;
cin >> *Ptr2;

int *Ptr3 = &Ptr1 - &Ptr2;
cout << Ptr3;

}
```

My problem is that when i declare the variables i have to put one float and one int, so the program don´t let me substract a float with an int.

Answer (score 0):

```
int *Ptr1;
int *Ptr2;


*Ptr1 = V1;
*Ptr2 = V2;
```

This is undefined behavior.  Ptr1 and Ptr2 are uninitialized, but you attempt to dereference them in the assignment statements.  You are trying to write values into random (uninitialized) memory locations.

```
int *Ptr3 = &Ptr1 - &Ptr2;
```

Here you use the & operator to take the addresses of Ptr1 and Ptr2 (which are already pointers!), then try to subtract the addresses, and use
that to initialize Ptr3.

None of this makes any sense.  You seem to be misunderstanding how pointers,
the & operator, and the * operator work.  Better make another pass through whatever reference materials you're working from...